# having error after last update to code for streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

having error after last update to code for streamlit it was working then suddenly stopped

```
ModuleNotFoundError: This app has encountered an error. The original error message is redacted to prevent data leaks. Full error details have been recorded in the logs (if you're on Streamlit Cloud, click on 'Manage app' in the lower right of your app).
```

Traceback:

```
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 556, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/status/app.py", line 17, in <module>
    import hydralit as hy
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hydralit/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from hydralit.hydra_app import HydraApp
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hydralit/hydra_app.py", line 4, in <module>
    from hydralit.sessionstate import SessionState
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hydralit/sessionstate.py", line 9, in <module>
    from streamlit.scriptrunner.script_run_context import get_script_run_ctx
```

if anyone can help would greatly appreciate it

Comment: Can you show the extra error messages from your logs, sanitized of any potential important data?

Comment: https://github.com/SalemGrayzi1/Diwan/blob/main/logs-salemgrayzi1-diwan-main-app.py-2022-08-13T18_01_20.207Z.txt that was the only way i could show you the whole thing

Comment: It looks like you're missing the [`streamlit-metrics`](https://pypi.org/project/streamlit-metrics/) module from your `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know but there still an error updated error message https://github.com/SalemGrayzi1/Diwan/blob/main/logs-salemgrayzi1-diwan-main-app.py-2022-08-14T09_34_09.103Z.txt

Comment: Your code seems like it's either out of date with what the current `streamlit` module contains or you need to change your imports. It's complaining about more missing imports - scroll all the way down and you will see that it's complaining about `streamlit.scriptrunner`, which doesn't seem to exist in current `streamlit` versions. You'll have to refer to the streamlit documentation because you'll probably have more problems and back-and-forth debugging in StackOverflow comments is going to be unproductive.

Comment: the things is it was working until i was updating the code and streamlit.scriptrunner i dont have it in my line of codes, its works locally though which made me surprised as to why it is not working suddenly upon deployment i tried doing everything from the beginning as a test it worked until i reached the code import hydralit as hy thats when the error showed up im guessing the hydralit packages in down currently as that the only explanation i can come up with, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

The import path for get_report_ctx has changed many times with Streamlit updates:

```
# Streamlit < 0.65
from streamlit.ReportThread import get_report_ctx

# Streamlit > 0.65
from streamlit.report_thread import get_report_ctx

# Streamlit > ~1.3
from streamlit.script_run_context import get_script_run_ctx as get_report_ctx

# Streamlit > ~1.8
from streamlit.scriptrunner.script_run_context import get_script_run_ctx as get_report_ctx

# Streamlit > ~1.12
from streamlit.runtime.scriptrunner.script_run_context import get_script_run_ctx as get_report_ctx
```

If your code is shared with users of differing Streamlit versions you could use something like this:

```
try:
    # Streamlit < 0.65
    from streamlit.ReportThread import get_report_ctx

except ModuleNotFoundError:
    try:
        # Streamlit > 0.65
        from streamlit.report_thread import get_report_ctx

    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        try:
            # Streamlit > ~1.3
            from streamlit.script_run_context import get_script_run_ctx as get_report_ctx

        except ModuleNotFoundError:
            try:
                # Streamlit > ~1.8
                from streamlit.scriptrunner.script_run_context import get_script_run_ctx as get_report_ctx

            except ModuleNotFoundError:
                # Streamlit > ~1.12
                from streamlit.runtime.scriptrunner.script_run_context import get_script_run_ctx as get_report_ctx
```